# How to use zip with different types?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the following code #1:

```
await cur.execute(query)
async for row in cur:
   if row[1] not in banned_doorbots:
      result.append({
            'ding_id': row[0],
            'doorbot_id': row[1],
            'kind': row[2]
})
return result
```

I'm refactored it to #2:

```
await cur.execute(query)
keys = ('ding_id', 'doorbot_id', 'kind')
return [dict(zip(keys, row)) async for row in cur
           if row[1] not in banned_doorbots]
```

But now I have a problem, my `ding_id` should contain `str` type,
like this `'ding_id': str(row[0])`

How can I use my #2 solution?

Comment: Do you have any example for `row`? Right now, it's impossible to test your code.

Comment: Are you trying to convert `row[0]` to a string, or is `row[0]` a string when you don't want it to be?

Comment: @jwodder convert `row[0]` to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
return [dict(zip(keys, [str(row[0])] + row[1:])) async for row in cur
           if row[1] not in banned_doorbots]
```

If `row` is a tuple, convert into a list first:

```
return [dict(zip(keys, [str(row[0])] + list(row[1:]))) async for row in cur
       if row[1] not in banned_doorbots]
```

Comment: You seem to have a parenthesis missing.

Comment: Thanks. Copy-paste problem. Fixed.

Comment: I have the following error: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`

Comment: Convert the rest of `row` into a list first. See my update answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) doesn't care about types and surely doesn't convert integers to a strings. The only thing that matters is that the arguments should be iterables (which seems to be the case in your example). The elements inside those iterables are left untouched, though.

```
keys = ('ding_id', 'doorbot_id', 'kind')
cur = [[1, 1000, 'a'], [2, 1002, 'b']]
print([dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in cur])
# [{'ding_id': 1, 'doorbot_id': 1000, 'kind': 'a'}, {'ding_id': 2, 'doorbot_id': 1002, 'kind': 'b'}]
```

You'll need to provide concrete examples of `row` and `cur`, but I really don't think that `zip` is the problem.

If you have a list of integers and want to convert it to strings, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> map(str, [1, 2, 3])
['1', '2', '3']
```